# Não consigo reproduzir sons usando o Pygame no Pycharrm

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

Estou tentando reproduzir áudios usando a biblioteca Pygame. O programa roda, mas o áudio não sai. Testei em dois computadores diferentes, e em ambos acontece o mesmo: o programa roda, não apresenta erro, mas o áudio não sai nos computadores. Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('ex021.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
pygame.event.wait()
```

O programa apresenta as seguintes mensagens:

```
"C:\Users\mauma\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\Mauricio\CURSOS\CURSO - PYTHON\PythonExerc\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/mauma/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/Mauricio/CURSOS/CURSO - PYTHON/DESAFIOS/DESAFIO 21.py"
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.4)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Tentei usar áudios nos formatos mp3 e wav, mas acontece sempre a mesma situação citada acima. Alguém tem ideia do que seja ou como resolver?
Obs: também usei as bibliotecas Pydub e Playsound, mas ocorre a mesma situação de rodar, não apresentar erro e o áudio não sair no computador.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Eu estou entendendo que o problema do usuário é que ele não consegue reproduzir o áudio. Qual é a dúvida da Comunidade???

Answer (score 0):

se o seu programa é só isso, ele simplesmente "acaba" e a música nunca vai começar a tocar. A ideia da biblioteca é justamente deixar a música tocando, numa thread separada, enquanto o seu programa segue em execução com sua lógica.

Voce colocou a chamada `pygame.event.wait()` ali, achando que talvez resolvesse isso - há uma forma de configurar um evento pra ser enviado quando a música acaba, mas seu programa não faz essa configuração.

Independente disso, a chamada `pygame.event.wait()` vai parar no *primeiro* evento que acontecer: um programa rodando em pygame recebe dezenas de eventos por segundo, em geral - desde eventos de teclado, qualquer movimetno no mouse, eventos que são disparados quando o `init()` é chamado, etc... ou seja, essa chamada vai retornar imediatamente.

Experimente pausar o programa por alguns segundos e veja se a música toca - use a chamada `pygame.time.delay(5000)` (aguarda 5 segundos, equivalente a `time.sleep(5)`.

Se ouvir algo, é esse o problema: só seguir implementando o programa. S ea ideia é que ele só toque a música mesmo, tem que configurar direitinho o evento de fim de música - veja a função [`set_end_event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent) - e crie um laço (um bloco `while` - no pygame cada programa é responsável pelo "laço principal" que é repetido a cada frame de um jogo, veja exemplos de programas pygame na rede) que fique recebendo os eventos e testando (com um "if" mesmo) se o evento é o específico que indica o final da faixa.
Se for um app que for usar a tela, é só continuar fazendo o restante do programa

Por fim, uma dica não diretamente relacionada com seu problema (mas pode sim ter a ver): você não escreve um programa python "para o Pycharm", ou usando o pycharm: o pycharm é um **editor de código** com um monte de ferramentas integradas pra facilitar o trabalho em projetos grandes. *Uma* dessas ferramentas pode executar o projeto que você está editando, mas o seu projeto está em arquivos do tipo ".py" no disco, e podem ser executados diretamente (em geral pela linha de comando, mas também pela interface gráfica, se estiver configurado).